# Capturing self in the block temporarily

Tags: swift

Having a runtime error when program is compiled, purposefully the instantiation of `SomeObject` is short lived but the block getting passed captures the reference, doesn't work in playground but shows the error when the program is compiled and run.

Objective is to hold the reference temporarily of short lived objects `SomeObject` until callback gets completed.

**Edit** - if I comment `[unowned self]` inside `go` it works, as I believe it creates a strong reference, but hopefully no memory leak there??? (the caller object went out of scope anyway). please confirm that I shouldn't use `[unowned self]` in here.

```
import Foundation

class SomeObject {

    func go() { //i guess problem is here, it can't find self,
        anotherObject.asyncCall({ [unowned self] in //works if i comment this
            self.complete()
        })
    }

    func complete() { //can't move this routine inside block, part of parent class api
        println("received callback after 5 sec")
    }
}

class AnotherObject {

    var callback: (() -> ())?

    init() {}

    func asyncCall(callback: () -> ()) {
        self.callback = callback

        let delay = 5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [unowned self] in
            self.callback!()
        })
    }
}

var anotherObject = AnotherObject() //not global object but permanent lived

for i in 1...3 { //can't change here, it's part of API that instantiates my objects
    var instance = SomeObject() //short lived objects
    instance.go()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please confirm that I shouldn't use `[unowned self]` in here

There's no need to concern yourself with memory management merely because an anonymous function mentions `self`.

If an anonymous function that mentions `self` is going to be a property of `self`, *then* you have a retain cycle and potential memory leak, and you should concern yourself with memory management. You can easily see whether you have a memory leak by implementing your `deinit` to log; if it doesn't log when you expect this object to be destroyed, it's leaking. If it is leaking, you might try using `[weak self]`, not `[unowned self]`. `unowned` is more convenient but it is usable only in very limited circumstances.

However, I see no evidence that the object that's going to retain the callback is the same object that is referred to in it as `self`. It looks to me more like the opposite: you seem to be using `[unowned self]` on every anonymous function, apparently without the slightest knowledge of what you are doing. That is extremely dangerous. You should not interfere with memory management unless you have to and unless you know how to. My advice is that you start by deleting every single `unowned` in your code. Then implement `deinit` and see if you have any actual leaking objects. I'm betting that you don't.

Comment: the deinit log thing really took the mystery out of it